# Generate custom status along with the error messages

Tags: java, status

How can I generate custom status and errorDetails messages. I am working on web services. Initially I was generating them randomly. Below is the code. But now, I would like to remove the random feature out of it. My whole goal is to set the exceptions (for example) with the error message and send it back to the client.

```
String[] status = { "SUCCESS", "ERROR", "LOCKED", "EXCEPTION" };
Random ran = new Random();
String gen = status[ran.nextInt(status.length)];
logger.debug("Status is" + status);
outData.setStatus(gen);

if (gen.equals("SUCCESS")) {
    outData.setErrorDetails("");
} else if (gen.equals("ERROR")) {
    outData.setErrorDetails("Usage of time code VAC is not allowed; balance is insufficient." + " error");
} else if (gen.equals("LOCKED")) {
    outData.setErrorDetails("Timesheet cannot be edited because it is locked for payroll close." + "locked");
} else if (gen.equals("EXCEPTION")) {
    outData.setErrorDetails("{ML}QR_INCORRECT_CONDITION_PARAMETER{/ML}Error in condition AWA Is Self Override Condition:java.lang.NullPointerException{ARGS}AWA Is Self Override Conditionjava.lang.NullPointerException{/ARGS" + "exception");
} 
returnList.add(outData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap. That will reduce your code.

Use something like -

```
Map<String, String> statusMsgMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
statusMsgMap.put("SUCCESS", "Your Success Message");
statusMsgMap.put("ERROR", "Your Error Message");
statusMsgMap.put("LOCKED", "Your Locked Message");
statusMsgMap.put("EXCEPTION", "Your Exception Message");

outData.setErrorDetails(statusMsgMap.get(gen));
```

Comment: Thank you. So in a case, suppose I have multiple exceptions in my whole java class, can I just set each exception to statusMsgMap.put("EXCEPTION", "With each particular exception msg"); Suppose it is a NullPointerException, I would like it to go as NPE, and if it is IO then should be sent as IO.

Comment: As of now you're checking like - gen.equals("EXCEPTION"). So how will you know which kind of exception it is?
You can't keep multiple values for same key in map. Check if you get different gen value for different exceptions, in that case you can keep individual msg for each of those different gen values

Comment: Until this time, the requirement was only to provide a random generated message. It was basically a stub. But now, the requirements have changed. The exact exception/error msg has to be sent back. I am trying to use a boolean as a global variable to do the error checking throughout the code and then send the msg with the custom status as SUCCESS/ERROR/EXCEPTION/LOCKED appropriately along with the msg rather than using the usual approach something like -- throw NPE("Message");

Comment: If you can know what exact kind of exception it is, and instead of getting gen value as "EXCEPTION" it is "IOEXCEPTION" or "NPEXCEPTION", you can add key value pairs for them as well.